# Wrong row count in materialUI table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, pagination, material-ui

I am using materialuI in react js to display data. In image one you can see the number of array/objects is 15 (total users is 15). When I navigate to last page , that means clicking 2 times in change page , the total number of data is shown as 21. but theres only 15 data. (PLEASE refer image 2)[second image shows 21 (number) is wrong. theres only 15 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHvyY.jpg)
[image of first page of data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhMJp.jpg)

```html
<TablePagination
  component="div"
  className="material-table__pagination"
  count={(list.number) || 0}
  rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
  page={page}
  backIconButtonProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Previous Page' }}
  nextIconButtonProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Next Page' }}
  onChangePage={handleChangePage}
  onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
  dir="ltr"
  SelectProps={{
    inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
    native: true
  }}
/>
```

Comment: You are just going too far, if you have 5 items per page, and 15 items, clicking the button 3 times takes you to a non existent 4th page. You should just limit the button presses / max page value etc.

Comment: my bad. 2 times. will edit it on the question. thanks